# Python disable list string "breaking"

Tags: python

Is there a way to disable breaking string with list. For example:

```
>>> a = "foo"
>>> b = list()
>>> b.append(list(a))
>>> b
>>>[['f', 'o', 'o']]
```

Is there a way to have a list inside of a list with string that is not "broken", for example `[["foo"],["bar"]]`?

Comment: `list(a)` is not `[a]`. Notice that `list(1)` does not create a list with a single element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very esay:

```
>>> a = "foo"
>>> b = list()
>>> b.append([a])
>>> b
[['foo']]
```

Comment: @lejlot: Yes: using `list` convert a string in char… But with banquets it's not the case. Yes?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
>>> a = "foo"
>>> b = list()
>>> b.append([a])
>>> b
[["foo"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that the `list` function works by taking each element of the sequence you pass it and putting them in a list. A string in Python is a sequence, the elements of the sequence are the individual characters.

Having this abstract concept of a "sequence" means that a lot of Python functions can work on multiple data types, as long as they accept a sequence. Once you get used to this idea, hopefully you'll start finding this concept more useful than surprising.

Answer (score -1):

you sound like you want to break on word boundaries instead of on each letter.

Try something like

```
a = "foo bar"
b = list()

b.append(a.split(' '))  # [['foo', 'bar']]
```

Example with RegEx (to support multiple consecutive spaces) :

```
import re
a = "foo       bar"
b.append(re.split(r'\s+', a))  # [['foo', 'bar']]
```